# Im stuck with this DATEDIFF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

Alright so I keep getting this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' Days ' to data type int.

Below is my code.....what am I doing wrong here....I am trying to show the day, hour and minute difference...I used the CASTS in my datediff because those were different columns so I used the cast to conjoin them to make it easier to do my datediff.....

```
DATEDIFF(DD, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME)) + ' Days ' 
        + DATEDIFF(HH, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME)) + ' Hours '
        + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME)) + ' Minutes'
AS Time_diff2,
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result will fetch better answers. You are adding two dates that doesn't sound logical `CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME)`

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand - 2011-09-20](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateDiff function will return result in integer. And here, you are combining Integer value and string value. Therefore, you are facing type difference error.

You have to cast datediff output to varchar as mentioned below

```
cast(DATEDIFF(DD, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME))as varchar(50)) + ' Days ' 
        + cast(DATEDIFF(HH, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME))as varchar(50)) + ' Hours '
        + cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME) + CAST(txt_signoff_ml_time AS DATETIME)) as varchar(50)) + ' Minutes'
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
DATEDIFF(DD, checkin_datetime, CAST(txt_signoff_ml_date AS DATETIME)
```

needs a closing bracket.  That should get you started.

Comment: Actually parenthesis are placed properly. Error is because of this concatenating `integer(Datediff result)` with `string(days)`. It can be fixed by explicit conversion still I dont think query is logically correct